# what's the general solution of Nonhomogeneous Linear Differential Equation with constant coefficients?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can we solve the differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}+\lambda^2 x = F$$
where $x=x(t),F=F(t)$ and $\lambda$ is constant.

I find an example from [This book](https://archive.org/stream/nasa_techdoc_19670020827/19670020827#page/n25/mode/2up), page 15. In this example, $F(t)=2\lambda(\int_{0}^{t} T(t) d\xi+C)+S(t)$, $\lambda$ and $C$ are constant. Then it gives the general form of solution:
$$
x = A \sin\lambda t + B\cos \lambda t + \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{t} F(\xi) \sin \lambda(t- \xi ) d\xi
$$

I can't understand how it is going.

Comment: @Moo Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many alternatives... The method  used to get your solution is the method of Green's functions, however, with this particular equation, the most beautiful approach (on my opinion) is as follows. The equation of motion is
$$\frac{d^{2}x(t)}{dt^{2}}+\omega^{2}x(t)=f(t)$$
Which you can write as
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+i\omega{x}(t)\Big)-i\omega\Big(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+i\omega{x}(t)\Big)=f(t)$$
By introducing $\xi(t)=\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+i\omega{x}(t)$ you get the first order equation
$$\frac{d\xi(t)}{dt}-i\omega\xi(t)=f(t)$$
Using the integrating factor we get
$$\xi(t)=e^{i\omega{t}}\Big\{c_{1}+\int_{0}^{t}f(t')e^{-i\omega{t}'}dt'\Big\}$$
Then you have the first order differential equation for $x(t)$
$$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}+i\omega{x}(t)=\xi(t)=e^{i\omega{t}}\Big\{c_{1}+\int_{0}^{t}f(t')e^{-i\omega{t}'}dt'\Big\}$$
Again using the integrating factor
$$x(t)=e^{-i\omega{t}}\Big(c_{2}+\int_{0}^{t}e^{i\omega{t'}}\Big\{c_{1}+\int_{0}^{t'}f(t'')e^{-i\omega{t}''}dt''\Big\}dt'\Big)$$

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. However, I've been puzzled about how to transform the double intergration into single intergration as the reference in the question. Can you give me a hint ?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to solve this equation. @Kiryl's is right and eligant. There is another approach, with [Laplace transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Using laplace transformation principle, we can transform the motion equation into
$$
   s^2 X(s) + \lambda^2 X(s) = F(s)
$$
where $X(s)$ and $F(s)$ are Laplace transformation of $x(t)$ and $F(t)$ respectively.

Then we get 
$$
      X(s) =  \frac{F(s)}{s^2+\lambda^2}
$$
Using the Laplace transformation properties, we get one special solution of the original equation:
$$
       x(t) = \frac{1}{\lambda} \int _0 ^t F(\xi) \sin \lambda (t-\xi) d \xi
$$